# Oracle database: Disabling Trigger updates when a specific column is altered?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, schema

I have the following existing `trigger` on the PERSON `table` in my WORKPLACE `schema`.

Currently, It updates the last_updated column automatically to the current date when any other column is altered.

**Trigger:**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WORKPLACE"."UPD_PERSON" 
    BEFORE update ON person 
    FOR each row 
 BEGIN 
    :new.last_updated := systimestamp; 
 END;
```

**Current table:**

```
 ID | Name | Created | last_updated | checked
```

I have a column within my table named 'checked' , how can I changed this trigger so that when the 'checked' column is changed, that the last_updated column is **NOT** changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:
*"An UPDATE statement might include a list of columns. If a triggering statement includes a column list, the trigger is fired only when one of the specified columns is updated"*

So insert a columns list for all columns except checked.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WORKPLACE"."UPD_PERSON" 
    BEFORE update of ID , Name , Created ON person 
    FOR each row 
 BEGIN 
    :new.last_updated := systimestamp; 
 END;
```

Comment: Thanks, although then I would have to change this every time I add a column? Is there a way to just exclude the 'CHECKED' column ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Alternatively you can make a trigger that fires for every update and check for every column change that will lead to an update of your timestamp. But you would still have to change that when adding columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `IF` condition. *"how can I changed this trigger so that when the 'checked' column is changed, that the last_updated column is NOT changed"* means *"update column last_updated only if 'checked' column is not changed"*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WORKPLACE"."UPD_PERSON" 
    BEFORE update ON person 
    FOR each row 
BEGIN 
   IF :old.checked = :new.checked THEN
      :new.last_updated := systimestamp; 
   END IF;
END;
```

Note, in case `checked` can be NULL, you have to verify also on NULL values, e.g.

```
IF :old.checked = :new.checked or (:old.checked IS NULL AND :new.checked IS NULL) THEN
```

You can put condition also in header like this (note the missing colon `:` in condition)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WORKPLACE"."UPD_PERSON" 
    BEFORE update ON person 
    FOR each row 
    WHEN (old.checked = new.checked)
BEGIN 
   :new.last_updated := systimestamp; 
END;
```

Comment: I basically want the functionality that when the 'checked' column is changed - the last_updated column does NOT get updated by the trigger. Does this answer solve this?

Comment: Yes, make `IF NOT :old.checked <> :new.checked THEN` if you prefer.

Comment: @java123999 But what if name and checked are both changed in the same update statement?

Comment: @Rene I do not think that issue will ever occur

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit please update the answer to show this, I am not understanding so far? thanks

Comment: @java123999, do you really have a problem to understand that `IF NOT :old.checked <> :new.checked THEN` is the same as `IF :old.checked = :new.checked THEN`?